# Why aren't images appearing when I load contents of a different page into the current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an index.html page with a container div. When I `load()` an external page into the container div, it works as far a text goes, but images are missing. Is there a way to fix that? I've ruled out cross-origin issues; both pages are on the same domain.

Here's my index.html page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Lakes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='div1_top'> 
      <h1>Lakes by state</h1>
      <p>This is some text.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      <li><a href="states/illinois.html">Illinois Lakes</a</li>
      <li><a href="#" id="indiana">Indiana Lakes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="iowa">Iowa Lakes</a></li>
    </div>
    <div id="content">This is where content goes</div>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
      $('#nav a').click(function(e) { 
        $('#content').hide().load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
          $('#content').show();
        });
        return false;
      });
    });

    </script>
  </body>     
</html>
```

Here's one of the external pages being loaded into the div on the index.html page.

```
<DOCTYPE = html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="image_lake">
      <img src="../img/lake-michigan.jpg" alt="lake Michigan" height="100" width="300">
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>illinois</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>This is just some random placeholder text.</h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should provide some examples or explain a bit deeply what exactly you want to achieve. I think what you need is an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_iframe.asp), if I deciphered your question correctly.

Comment: Can you check in the web inspector which error codes are getting the queries to the images? If they're 404 I think that this can be because of the image path. You should define the src on the images with the absolute url address.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to state and summarize the problem in question form. I also made the body less verbose and more explicit, and formatted the code for maximum readability.

Comment: You are using relatively pathed image src's. This is fine until the page you're loading the images on, is no longer the same relative path away from the image src. Try starting all your image src's with `/` rather than `../` so that they are relative to the "root" of your site. That way, all pages using the same image src will correctly link to it.

Comment: PS. instead of `.load`, you should probably `.get()`, then load the contents into a jQuery object. Then find the contents of the `body` and replace your `#contents` div's content with that. Otherwise you're potentially inserting `script` and `style` tags, and invalid secondary `html`, `head`, and `body` tags.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the source images are using Relative URLs.
The fix is to include the basehref of the images origin, or convert their relative paths to absolute ones. 
Otherwise, the images have been protected on the server side.